# Django and Python 3, If POST value equals not working

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-3.x, django-models

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_date
```

I'm trying to be able to either request database logs from either a set period of hours, or a custom time range. When sending through the custom time range, I use a value of `0` and convert it to an `int` to measure it:

```
    camera_id = request.GET.get('camera_id', None)
    range = request.GET.get('range', None)
    start = request.GET.get('start', None)
    end = request.GET.get('end', None)

    if int(range) == 0:
        end_date = parse_date(start)
        start_date = parse_date(end)
    else:
        end_date = datetime.now()
        start_date = end_date - timedelta(hours=int(range))

    data = []

    camera_logs = CameraLog.objects.filter(camera_id=camera_id, created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

But I'm not getting anything back from the database when choosing a custom date range. I get data back when requesting a standard hourly range (like 3), but I'm not even sure that my dates are being parsed properly.

I really don't think that `if int(range) == 0:` is ever true ... and I have no idea why. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `parse_date` expects `start` and `end` to be dates with format `yyyy-mm-dd`, otherwise it will return None.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille as in, it can't have a timestamp too? I'm sending a string that looks like this: `2017-02-22 17:01:04`

Comment: Exactly. You have to use `parse_datetime` in this case.

Comment: I really don't think that `if int(range) == 0:` is ever true ... any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment, this may just be a typo in your example, or it may be correct and i'm misunderstanding. Shouldn't you be using the `>=` operator instead of the `<=` operator? I'm assuming your not testing for a negative int but a positive one correct?

Comment: It could be `==` too ... im basically checking if the value being posted is `0`. If it's not `0` then it's a number that I want to use for my hour range.